# BIRT adjust grid row height according to chart height

Tags: birt

I am setting the height of a chart through javascript inside html of text item. However, the grid row height remains constant and therefore, sometimes there is too much white space

I want to adjsut row height according to chart height. Please help me

Regards
Arif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just leave the height property of the row to blank, it will automatically be adjusted to the size of the content, in your case the height of the chart + your margins/paddings. You should also pay attention if the grid itself has a height defined.

As soon as an element has a dynamic height,  most of the time we have to remove "height" properties defined in its containers